# What is this pseudo-element applied to?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, handsontable

Consider my css has this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

What is this applied to? It's not applied to `html` or `body`. But to what?

I'm trying to style scrollbars on a component of some lib (handsontable), but it renders funny, because its JS code is reading scrollbar sizes from *somewhere*.

[image]

The css above fixes that. But then it sets scrollbar sizes everywhere in the app, which is undesirable. I'm looking for a workaround. If I do something like:

```
html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

or same with any class that is a parent of the component, I'm not getting the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

is the same as this:

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

So it applies to all elements.

> [**§ 6.2. Universal
>   selector**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#universal-selector)
>
> If a universal selector represented by `*` is not the only component
>   of a sequence of simple selectors or is immediately followed by a
>   pseudo-element, then the `*` may be omitted and the universal
>   selector's presence implied.